# Android Sync Failure after adding onesignal-gradle-plugin

Tags: android, react-native, onesignal

I'm trying to add push notifications to my react-native project using OneSignal React-Native SDK. I managed to get it work on IOS but not on android as the build keep failing after I modified `app/build.gradle` file to add the `onesignal-gradle-plugin`.

Here is the code that I added on top of `app/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
}
}
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

When I Sync the android project. It produced these errors:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:12.0.1
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:12.0.1
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:12.0.1
>
> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:12.0.1

Comment: Check if your project level dependencies need to upgraded. If so, do it

Comment: Thanks, actually it solved by removing these code in build.gradle :

`if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') { details.useVersion '12.0.1' }`